# Python PIP Path in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I just installed Python 2.7.10, Release Date: 2015-05-23 in Windows. Then I tried to call PIP via the shell, which failed. So I assumed that the Scripts directory in of Python had not been added to the Path Variable. However, it had been added, but as

```
 C:\Program Files\Python27\Scripts;
```

instead of

```
 C:\Program Files\Python27\Scripts\;
```

I added the later and PIP immediately worked. Is it safe now to delete the former? And how can I notify the developers of this bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it safe now to delete the former?

Yes, as Zach mentioned you can edit your PATH to whatever you like, the worst that could happen is some program that uses `$PATH` will no longer be able to find that executable, in which case you can just add it back to PATH.

> And how can I notify the developers of this bug?

That's not necessary, because this is not a bug. I am on windows 10, same python version as you, and my PATH has `C:\Python27\Scripts;` and it works fine. It recognizes `pip` as a command.

It doesn't matter whether you add the trailing `\` or not. Same as you can `cd` into a folder without appending a `\` to its name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess, I must have done something wrong, since I now removed the entry with the trailing backslash and it still works fine. Sorry for bothering and thanks for the help.

Comment: @Skrodde That is ok. Remember after you edit the PATH variable you should restart any command prompt or whatever you are working with so it can reload the value for PATH. There are other ways to reload it, but restarting the prompt is usually easier

Comment: This sounds a lot like an explanation to the problem I encountered!

Answer (score 0):

As far as modifying your PATH goes, you can add/remove whatever you like so long as you are sure you want to. In this case, you could easily change it back if something was amiss.

You can go to the [GitHub Issues Page](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues) for the PIP project and add an issue. Be sure to check and see if this issue already exists, first.